# Generating random but unique 4-digit numbers i Google Spreadsheet

Tags: random, unique, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that I would like to generate a column og random, but unique 4 digit numbers.
I have tried using "RANDBETWEEN" but this doesn't ensure that the numbers are unique, neither does it force 4-digit padding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel:

Column A: =Rand() 'generates a random decimal number between 0 and 1

Column B: =Rank(A1,$A$1:$A$1000) + 999 ' ranks the random decimals from 1 to 1000 and creates a 4 digit number

Yes, it uses a helper column, but it's simple and fast!

Will

Comment: Nice find ! ~99.99999999999999% chance we won't get the same number twice